# 301 redirect to the rewrited url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The CMS i am working with has these rewrite rules:

For the tags:

```
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)/$ tag.php?t=$1&page=1
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)(/)?$ tag.php?t=$1&page=$2
```

for the category pages:

```
RewriteRule ^browse-(.*)-videos.html$ category.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^browse-(.*)-videos-([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ category.php?cat=$1&page=$2&sortby=$3
```

But it does not redirect to the seo friendly url estructure creating duplicate content issues, how can i make so it also 301 redirects to the rewrited url if accessed from the other?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 4 new rules and place them above your existing.

```
#redirect old URL to new SEO
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+tag\.php\?t=([^&\s]+)&page=1
RewriteRule ^ /tags/%1/? [R=301,L]
#redirect old URL to new SEO
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+tag\.php\?t=([^&\s]+)&page=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /tags/%1/page-%2/? [R=301,L]
#redirect old URL to new SEO
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+category\.php\?cat=([^&\s]+)&page=([^&\s]+)&sortby=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /browse-%1-videos-%2-%3.html? [R=301,L]
#redirect old URL to new SEO
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+category\.php\?cat=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /browse-%1-videos.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)/$ tag.php?t=$1&page=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)(/)?$ tag.php?t=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^browse-(.*)-videos.html$ category.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^browse-(.*)-videos-([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ category.php?cat=$1&page=$2&sortby=$3 [L]
```

Comment: did not work it redirects to domain.com/xxxx/public_html/browse--videos.html

Comment: Yes my mistake. I used the wrong backreference. Also your server apparently needs the `/`before the URI. Try the updated rule. Clear you browser cache before trying my updated rules.

Comment: With this new rule the tags works perfect but the category does not for example: domain.com/category.php?cat=fun redirects to domain.com/browse-fun-videos.html while should redirect to domain.com/browse-fun-videos-1-date.html... domain.com/category.php?cat=fun&page=2 redirects also to domain.com/browse-fun-videos.html while the correct would be domain.com/browse-fun-videos-2-date.html and domain.com/category.php?cat=fun&page=1&sortby=title and videos-1-title.html and domain.com/category.php?cat=fun&page=2&sortby=title redirect to the same domain.com/browse-fun-videos.html

Comment: while the correct redirect would be domain.com/browse-fun-videos-1-title.html and domain.com/browse-fun-videos-2-title.html

Comment: Probably the easiest fix is change order of the rules. Clear your cache and try the update.

Comment: Got another another that you may be abe to help without starting another post...the rule is RewriteRule ^(.*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}).html$ watch.php?vid=$2 how to 301 redirect to the seoed url? thanks in advance

Comment: I can't see how this will work `^(.*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}).html` The first part seems like it can be any value. Is that right? There is no way to tell what will come before the `_` from the original like `watch.php?vid=1234` because the after the `_` would be `1234`. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: the CMS is a mess...this is on the mobile site, the same rule for the desktop which i have managed to redirect with php was RewriteRule ^([^/]*)_(.*).html$ watch.php?vid=$2 but on the mobile is the one

Comment: What does the actual URI look like?

Comment: the url in mobile and desktop is the same the only difference is that the mobile is on  the mobile folder but the url itself is the same in both...the urls is /title-of-video_vidid.html and no seoed /watch.php?vid=vidid where vidid are the same numbers in both

Comment: The problem is there is no title attached to `watch.ph?vid=id` just the id. So it won't be able to redirect to the same html file format of `title-of-video_vidid.html` because title will be blank.

Comment: I see...i guess i will need to manage the mobile as i did on the desktop with php..thanks so much for your time

Comment: sorry to bother you again...on the mobile i have the same exact issue with the categories... the mobile site is located on domain.com/mobile/ and has its own .htaccess file i have applied the same solution in its .htaccess but does not work, does not redirect al all

Comment: Ok please open another question with your current issue you are having.